# Question about $m$-dimensional column vector

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I construct a linear map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^m$  that could be expressed as multiplication by an $m \times n$ matrix?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: $C$ is the field of complex numbers, isn'i it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matrix you are trying to find depends upon your choice of basis. If you choose the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ then your matrix is given by the $m\times n$ matrix whose columns are $m$-vectors which are the images of basis elements.

Let $T:\mathbb{C}^{n}$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{C}^{m}$ and $A$ be your matrix that induces your map $T$ then the matrix $A$ is given by

$$A = [T(e_1)  T(e_{2})...T(e_{n})].$$

Answer (score 1):

One such map could be $f(x) = Ax, x \in \mathbb{C^n}$, with $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix.